# List android.widget API controls dynamically

Tags: android

How to show the list of available ui controls from the android.widget API dynamically?

Comment: please help me on this.

Still i can't to find the answer

Answer (score 0):

When creating an xml layout file in eclipse, on the left of the graphical layout tab are all the android widgets.